# CSS doesn't load after migration of magento website

Tags: css, magento, migration, e-commerce

I migrated my magento website to a different server, following the steps described [here](http://activecodeline.com/moving-magento-site-from-development-to-live-server). Everything went smoothly, except for the fact that when I load the page, the CSS won't load, and I just get the page in plain text.

I used firebug and noticed that the path the system is using to get to the CSS file doesn't exist in the FTP server. It starts with the 'minify' folder, which makes me think that something might be cached from the previous server.

An example:

my_site_url/minify/1281335374/skin/frontend/default/hellouno/css/styles.css

This path doesn't exist, not even in the previous server, so I'm thinking maybe these files are supposed to be generated on the fly? I'm really confused, any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your `.htaccess` file. Minification rewrites are handled there. If you haven't already, make sure your `.htaccess` file came over in the transfer, and make the appropriate changes if directories or anything else has been changed.

Comment: The .htaccess came over, and everything seems to be OK with it. The system is in the server's root folder, just like it was before in the previous server. Should anything have to change in the .htaccess file?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(index.php/)?minify/([^/]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ lib/minify/m.php?f=$3&d;=$ - Is this anywhere in there?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the problem was a missing Slash "/" at the end of the domain.

Use the following to get both rows:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' OR path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Then update them manually and make sure the domain has it's final "/", otherwise it will merge the domain name with the following folder name.

You can check whether this is your condition if when doing inspect, you see a wrong path to CSS and JS.

Correct Config:

[image]

Incorrect Config Results in:

[image]

- Remember to clear the var/cache folder.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume you cleared your cache out.  If "not having CSS" makes this hard to do via the admin, just delete the

```
var/cache
```

folder.

Sometimes giving the CSS (or Javascript) merge settings a quick toggle from on, to off, to on again will force Magento to recalculate the paths.

```
System -> Developer -> CSS Settings
```

If you can't access this in the Admin, change the value manually in the database table `core_config_data` (identified by the path column having the value `dev/css/merge_css_files`), clear your cache and reload your page

Comment: +1 as well, as that merge_css_files would be crucial in getting you back going if it was a critical situation

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Now I have to find a way to force the cache to clear, cause most images aren't being displayed.

Comment: Setting merge_css_files and merge_js_files value = 0, clearing cache via the file system, and refreshing the browser fixed me right up.  Thanks (again) Alan!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks its helped me i just forget to place / in the end of the path.

Before:

Base URL http://mywebsitename.com

After:

Base URL http://mywebsitename.com/

Its solved all skin/css and admin problem. Cheeers

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue, by changing the merge css options in the backend to no
It was a bit difficult to navigate through backend without css but managed to get there! 
**System > Configuration > Developer > CSS Settings**

Comment: This fixed it for me too. Had to use phpMyAdmin to search the 'core_config_data' table for a record where the 'path' field contains 'dev/css/merge_css_files' and set its value to '0' (i.e. zero == false). After that I deleted everything from the 'var/cache' folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed your site information (url and such) in the backend (or in the database) after the migration, this is the likely problem.
http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_configuration.htm#base_url
for the database:
in the core_config_data table
change key  "web/unsecure/base_url" to your site base url ex. http://yoursite.com
good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I did that. Everything seems to point to the right domain.

Comment: try adding a slash to the end and deleting everything in var/cache

Answer (score 1):

Experienced same problem once. 
The solution: 
I'd forgotten to put trailing slashes at the end of my base_urls when I'd updated them

**System > Configuration > General > Web > Unsecure**

```
Base URL http://mybaseurl.com/
```

**System > Configuration > General > Web > Unsecure**

```
Base URL https://mybaseurl.com/
```

If you're Admin section is out of bounds you can also set this value in the database in the table **core_config_data**

Fields: web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url

Also: Remember to flush your cache after doing this.

Comment: the key is to flush cache afterward. this worked for me. very important

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions for the folders like app/etc, var, media folders. Try to give 755 permissions to those folders. Recently I have faced the same problem and I tried with this. Then my site works fine.

Comment: John is right if you see your prototype was introduced with a url like, "/www/web/YOUR_SITE/public_html/js/prototype/prototype.js". Check permissions of those directories.

Comment: DONT give 777 to app/etc. thats where your database information is. anybody could waltz in and take that information from the website. i reiterate. dont set app/etc to 777

Answer (score 1):

Change Permission Of Skin And Media  Containing **All Folder TO Give Permission 755** And **File TO 644**

Answer (score 0):

Mine was also the forward slash ( / ) at the end of the url in the sql database. Cleared Cache and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

One answer that has not been given yet that turned out to be the solution to my problem:

When transferring the Magento store from 1 host to another, what usually isn't copied over is the VirtualHost entry. In my case I had to manually recreate this and wrongfully added `AllowOverride None`. This should be `AllowOverride All` in order for `.htaccess` files to be read and processed.